# Adding custom tasks to the web site page in IIS 7(.5)

Tags: iis-7, extensibility

Is it possible to add a TaskItem (or TaskList) to the website page (Web Objects Home Page)?

I'd like to provide some contextual access to my addin and I can't seem to find a good integration point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to [CarlosAg](http://forums.iis.net/members/CarlosAg.aspx) on the IIS.net forums for the basis of this answer.

1. Create a class that subclasses [ProtocolProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.extensions.protocolprovider(loband).aspx) and have it return a [TaskList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.tasklist(loband).aspx) by overriding [GetSiteTaskList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.extensions.protocolprovider.getsitetasklist(loband).aspx) and [GetSitesTaskList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.extensions.protocolprovider.getsitestasklist(loband).aspx).
2. In your Module.Initialize method, get an [IExtensibilityManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.iextensibilitymanager(VS.85,loband).aspx) from the serviceProvider
3. Register an instance of your ProtocolProvider to the IExtensibilityManager by calling [RegisterExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.iextensibilitymanager.registerextension(VS.85,loband).aspx).

**Update**

It turns out a ProtocolProvider can only provide a TaskList for the "Sites" view, but can provide a different TaskList depending on which site is selected (if any).

To provide a custom TaskList for a site's homepage (ie. with the list of features), you need to implement [IHomepageTaskListProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.extensions.ihomepagetasklistprovider(loband).aspx) and register it with the [IExtensibilityManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.iextensibilitymanager(VS.85,loband).aspx) mentioned above.

Within the [IHomepageTaskListProvider.GetTaskList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.extensions.ihomepagetasklistprovider.gettasklist(loband).aspx) implementation, you can find out if you the current "homepage" is a site or global by getting a [Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.client.connection(loband).aspx) from the [IServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider(loband).aspx) and checking the ConfigurationPath.PathType property (it's an [ConfigurationPathType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.server.configurationpathtype(loband).aspx) enumeration)

Comment: @CarlosAg: If you end up deciding to post, I'll mark yours as the answer.